# Why are values from numpy.linspace less precise than other numpy.float64 values?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I would like to generate numpy arrays with a decimal spacing, e.g. [0.05, 0.10, 0.15...]. The function [np.linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) seems appropriate, as the examples include float arrays. However, I cannot understand the results I'm getting:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(2110.35, 2149.05, 775)
print(x[-1], type(x[-1]))
print(x[-3], type(x[-3]))

    2149.05 <class 'numpy.float64'>
    2148.9500000000003 <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Most values are what I expect, but `x[-3]` is not. I thought that perhaps 2148.95 can't be stored any more accurately as a np.float64, but this doesn't seem to be true:

```
y = np.float64(2148.95)
print(y, type(y))

    2148.95 <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

This causes a problem when I want to use a comparison operator:

```
x[-3] <= y
    False
```

Why is this happening?

What can I do to safely obtain the sort of arrays I want?

(I apologize if I misused technical language, I don't know much about floating-point maths)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: No it does not.
I understand that np.float64(2148.95) is not stored as the true decimal number 2148.95. I don't know why it appears as such in one case and not the other. I don't know why all values of x, except x[-3], print and compare as expected.

Comment: Equality test  (including `<=`) on floats is not 'safe'.  This is the float point issue.  Look at the range for your values, `2149.05-2110.35`.  I get `38.70000000000027`

Comment: @xxyxxyxyx1 -- There is one big reason, in addition to the usual suspect of "inherent limitation of fp-representation". Your input values to `linspace()` are wrong, in the first place, given your expectation of a spacing of `0.05`. Please see my edited answer for a complete set of reasons.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2020-11-21: (Added section starting here)**

**Reason for discrepancy:**

A peek at the [source code for `numpy.linspace`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/function_base.py) reveals the following:

1. First, the `step` is calculated from given `start`, `stop`, and `num`. There's only one way to do this, and there's nothing wrong or imprecise in how `step` is being computed.
2. Successive output values are produced by taking the base value of `start`, and adding increasingly higher multiples of `step`, to the `start` value. So, for example, the first value is produced by adding `(0 * step)` to `start`, and the next value is produced by adding `(1 * step)` to `start`, and so on. Again, nothing wrong or unusual or imprecise in this. Remember that the primary promises of `linspace()` are to ensure **uniformity** of the spacing, and to ensure that exactly the requested number of samples are output.
3. If `endpoint=True` in the call to `linspace()`, the last output value is **forced** to be equal to the specified `stop` value. Again, for most use-cases, this would seem the more desirable thing to do, rather than outputting a computed value as the last value, no matter how cleverly the last value is computed.

So, where is the imprecision coming from?

I can think of three reasons for the discrepancy being discussed here:

1. **Wrong expectation for the given input values of `start`, `stop` and `num`**: Even in an ideal world where there are no inherent limitations in FP representation, it is **impossible** for `x[-3]` to equal `2148.95`, when `start=2110.35`, `stop=2149.05`, and `num=775`. It may be possible **only** if these input values were slightly different, for example `num=776` instead of `num=775` -- in which case `(stop - start)/(776-1)` would be a nice round spacing of `0.05`, which means it would then be reasonable to expect `x[-3]` to equal `2148.95`.
2. The `start` and `start` values themselves happen to be incapable of being precisely represented in FP. (Remember that most fractions can be represented in FP only with some imprecision. The notable exceptions are fractions that are negative powers of `2`). So, with `start` and `stop`, what we see is not what the computer sees. This obviously affects the computation of `step`. The imprecision in this computed `step` is `num` times less than the imprecision in `(stop - start)`. However, note that towards the end of the output sequence, this imprecision in `(stop - start)` will have an increasing impact, as increasingly higher multiples of `step` get added to `start`. Here's a demonstration of this:

```
    print (format(2110.35, ".40g"))
    print (format(2149.05, ".40g"))
    print (format(0.125, ".40g"))  # 0.125 is an FP-friendly vaue (it is 2**(-3))
```

outputs:

```
    2110.349999999999909050529822707176208496
    2149.050000000000181898940354585647583008
    0.125
```

3. (As OP is already aware) Each computed output value (however precisely the computation is done), may or may not be representable precisely in FP. In practice, this inherent imprecision of FP will affect most of the generated output values.

Hypothetically speaking, it could be argued that perhaps `numpy` developers could have inserted extra interventional logic -- they could have tried to somehow figure out which of the output values **can** be precisely represented in FP, and for those output positions, they could output **forced** true values rather than computed values. Such an intervention **is** currently being done for the last output value, when `endpoint=True`. However, such excessive intervention would violate the primary promise of **regularity** of spacing, in addition to affecting the speed.

Another hypothetical debate could be on whether the successive values could be generated by cumulative addition, rather than by `(start + i*step)`. That is, the second value could be computed as `(first + step)`, the third could be computed as `(second + step)`, and so on. I am not sure why such an implementation was not chosen, but I doubt that will get us any benefits in precision. The factors that I suspect to be causing the imprecision now, would still apply (the inherent limitation of FP representation for precisely representing the computed values, and the imprecision in `start`, `stop` and `step`). It will also probably be slower, since each value can be computed only after the previous one has been computed.

To **summarize**, rather than the `linspace` algorithm being sub-optimal, the real culpable reasons are -- wrong expectation (or wrong input), and inherent limitation of FP representation affects `start`, `stop`, and the computed values.

**Edit 2020-11-21: (Added section ends here)**

Your little test:

```
print(y, type(y))
```

producing the output:

```
2148.95 <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

does not necessarily prove that `y` contains exactly `2148.95`.

That's because, when you call `print(y)`, it internally invokes `str(y)`, and we really don't know too much about the precision to which `str(y)` produces its output.

**Suggested Actions:**

1. In the invocation of `linspace()`, change `num=775` to `num=776`, to match your expectation of `step=0.05`
2. To perform test such as `if x[-3] <= y:`, do something like `if round(x[-3],5) <= round(y,5):` instead (here, I'm assuming that you care about no more than 5 digits after the decimal point).

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- Edited, thanks. Would appreciate if you take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I had understood that all decimal values are approximated in floats. However, I expected `np.linspace()` to provide floats with the closest possible value to the true value. I now understand why this is not how this, nor most other functions behave.

The functions `format()` and `np.nextafter()` helped me understand:

```
x = np.linspace(2110.35, 2149.05, 775)
y = np.float64(2148.95)
print('y:')
print(format(y, '.20g'))
print('x[-3]:')
print(format(x[-3], '.20g'))
print('the next float after y:')
print(format(np.nextafter(y, y+1), '.20g'))

    y:
    2148.9499999999998181
    x[-3]:
    2148.9500000000002728
    next float above y:
    2148.9500000000002728
```

The result from linspace is not the closest float to the decimal value 2148.95. The floating-point maths done by np.linspace to generate the array introduce errors beyond the minimal inherent decimal-to-float64 error.

Thank you @fountainhead, `round()` solves my problem by providing the closest float to the true decimal:

```
print('x[-3] rounded:')
print(format(round(x[-3], 2), '.20g'))

    x[-3] rounded:
    2148.9499999999998181
```

In my case, where I always have two decimal places, I can continue to use `<=`. In other situations, I will test for a difference less than some epsilon.